# iOS PhoneGap app using WebGL

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, webgl

Which is the WebView of a PhoneGap app, is the Safari mobile or desktop one?

Is it possible to use WebGL in PhoneGap apps? If not which they work around to use them being able to submit the app to the Apple Store and Android Store

Will I be able to submit to Apple Store a PhoneGap app that uses WebGL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE:

iOS 8 brought WebGL support on the UIWebView and WKWebView, so if you don't want to support previous versions you can use it without CocoonJS

See more details on [ludei's website](http://blog.ludei.com/webgl-ios-8-safari-webview/)

OLD:

If you want to create HTML5 apps with WebGL for iOS and android, try [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/)

Right now it's the only way to create WebGL apps that run on iOS and android

Comment: why does? differences with phonegap?

Comment: phonegap subclass UIWebView on iOS and android WebView, cocoonJS is based on chromium. Download the cocoonJS app from the app store to see the demos. You can even test your html from a link and compare it the performance on the regular webview and using the cocoon webview

Comment: thank you, does chronium webview based apps will pass the submission process both on Play store and Apple store? :O

Comment: Sure, the flappy bird game was made with cocoonJS and the CocoonJS app is in the app store too

Comment: that's cool, so CocoonJS is actually supporting all the main Chromium features? such as webGL, webRTC etc? @jcesar

Comment: I don't know, they don't mention webRTC on the html5 feature list, just webSockets http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/200807787-HTML5-feature-list

Comment: according to this tweet (from november 2013) they don't support webRTC https://twitter.com/ludei/status/405853973309300737

Comment: could be great to know which of the chromium features are available before to use it anyway thanks, there are too old tweets and infos about actually :P

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out your issues in two points.They are-

**phonegap build app links won't open in safari. For More details Please check [HERE](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_app_links_wont_open_in_safari)**

**Neither the iOS nor Android browsers support WebGL so it is pretty much a non-starter in PhoneGap.**

Apple are clearly working towards supporting WebGL in a more general sense, as can be seen in their support for it in iAds.

It’s possible to take advantage of WebGL using standard embedded web views ( using private APIs).

check [HERE](http://caniuse.com/webgl) too fro browser support.

Comment: so actually any way to use webGL on ios apps? or it's just phonegap please if you can add more details thanks

Comment: also i'm talking about links, i'm talking about webview, if it uses a specific webview such as Safari, Chrome etc

Comment: @sbaaaang your question is genuine and contain many questions.. I just explored my point of view from different resources. Apple is working on implementation of WebGl in iOS..

Comment: still not definitive answer but thank you i appriciate really

Comment: @sbaaaang very hard that u will get ur answer... i really want to know..what is ur actual doubt...i think i have answered your question

Comment: You said "Neither the iOS nor Android browsers support WebGL",but I see Android supports WebGL

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend Ejecta for it being open source:

https://github.com/phoboslab/Ejecta

The Android port doesn't seem widely active, but the main ios port seems well maintained, supporting WebGl.

The latest Android versions support webGL directly - if using older Android versions, Crosswalk can also be used along with phonegap to utilize webgl support.

https://crosswalk-project.org/