# Panorama 360 viewer with phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, panoramas

I read a lot of answers but i dont know wich is correct. Almost mobile browsers doesn support WEBGL, only newest. Almost script, libraries or plugins works with FLASH or WEBGL. I see and read a lot of your documentations and i dont know what to do. I need compatibility with almost smartphones in android and ios. I wanna use PHONEGAP platform to buil the app.
Can you guide me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) instead of Cordova.

Check the Answer of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147968/ios-phonegap-app-using-webgl)